# Any alternatives for plotting (long) time series?

Tags: time-series, data-visualization

I'm looking for ways to visualize large time-series other then in traditional 2-axis line charts. More specifically, I hope to find a way that intuitively reveals patterns in the data such as the spiral approach found in http://ieg.ifs.tuwien.ac.at/~aigner/teaching/ws06/infovis_ue/papers/spiralgraph_weber01visualizing.pdf
In my case, since I'm working with sensor data to track ones movements, days are a suitable interval. Another benefit of using spirals is that it doesn't require a linear increase in pixel space.

Other ideas: Overlaying data from multiple days on the same 24-hour x-axis or displaying the days individually, similar to a calendar.

Is there a better way? Any tips?

Comment: William Cleveland has a really nice division of a time series into several components near the beginning of one of his books (I am not at the office so I am not sure which of his two books it's in). There's a seasonal component, a trend component, a residual component and one other one. This lets you see different patterns easily.

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking of focusing on anomalies as a way of contextualizing the data, and using these components might be one way. I'll try and get a hold of his material, thank you.

Comment: The graph I am talking about is on p 7 of The Elements of Graphing Data.

Answer (score 2):

As you note, you could use an x axis showing 24 hours, then plot multiple days' data against this axis. This should reveal any intradaily patterns.

Alternatively, the x axis could run from Monday to Sunday, and you could plot each week's observations. This should show intraweekly (and intradaily) patterns; the weekend usually exhibits different patterns than the rest of the week.

Both are examples of *seasonal plots*; see [here](http://otexts.com/fpp/2/1/), also for other ideas for visualization.

Comment: +1 - I've seen other examples of spiral graphs as well, they seem really hard to digest (especially when they are noisy and many series) compared to well designed seasonal line charts.